# Why do we need to define MicroMutableOpResolver or AllOpsResolver for a particular model before calling an MicroInterpreter in tensorflow-lite?

Tags: tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-lite

I am currently trying to build a tflite model for a microcontroller. While creating the test file I came across a peice of code where in the test file was using a MicroMutableOpResolver to load model architecture. But I had already included the c dump of the model in my code then why is it using the resolver? Is it that the C dump of the model doesn't have any information of model architecture and contains only weights? Or is it something that I am missing?

[Here is the snippet of the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7tDhR.png)

Answer (score 1):

**MicroMutableOpResolver** loads the subset of operations needed for your model to be interpreted by **MicroInterpreter**. Alternatively **AllOpsResolver** which loads all of the operations available can be used, but it is not recommended due to heavy memory usage.

See also: [Instantiate operations resolver](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/microcontrollers/get_started_low_level#6_instantiate_operations_resolver)